# Causal Markov condition simple explanation

Tags: conditional-probability, causality

I am trying to explain in simple words the Causal Markov condition to establish probabilistic causation.  The definition from [Hausman and Woodward (1999)](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/epdf/10.1093/bjps/50.4.521) is the following:

> Let G be a causal graph with vertex set V and P be a probability distribution
> over the vertices in V generated by the causal structure represented by G. G
> and P satisfy the Causal Markov Condition if and only if for every X in V, X
> is independent of V\(Descendants(X) ∪ Parents(X)) given Parents(X)

My explanation is that a Causal Markov condition is satisfied if the set of  variables in a causal relationship with given probability distributions are independent of all the other variables unless they are their parents or their descendants.  This is slightly different than other definitions around so, is my explanation first, correct?, second clear?
Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: You have omitted the last clause from Hausman and Woodward's definition: "given Parents(X)". Without that clause, both the definition and your restatement of it are incorrect.

Comment: Note also that Hausman and Woodward (1999) did not originally define the Causal Markov Condition. They clearly cited Spirtes, Glymour and Scheines' book _Causation, Prediction and Search_, and note that the CMC was "apparently first described by Kiiveri and Speed (1982)".

Comment: Y doesn't seem to be quantified anywhere in the definition.

Comment: Just got both the Kiiveri paper and the Spirtes, Scheines and Glymour book.  References corrected.  Also added the last missing clause.  Fortunately it was included in my original Ms.  Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to think about the Causal Markov Condition (CMC) is giving a rule for "screening off": once you know the values of $X$'s parents, all other variables in $V$ become irrelevant for predicting $X$, except for $X$'s descendants.

I find examples make the CMC easiest to understand. I did a quick google image search for "mechanism of cardiovascular disease" so I can give you a medical example. Take this graph (let's call it $G$):

[image: mechanism of cardiovascular disease. Source: Nat Clin Pract Cardiovasc Med (2008) Nature Publishing Group]

Say you have a probability distribution $P$ over the variables in $G$. If the CMC holds in $P$ (relative to $G$), then you can infer that:

- If I know the patient's amount of *Oxidative stress and inflammation*, then learning the patient's degree of *Plaque progression* won't give me any **extra** information about the patient's *Platelets*.
- If I know the patient's amount of *Atheroma*, then learning the amount of *Oxidative stress and inflammation* won't help me predict *Plaque progression*.

However, the CMC **allows** the following possibilities:

- If I know the patient's amount of *Atheroma*, then learning the patient's degree of *Plaque rupture* might still tell me something more about *Plaque progression*. (I'm learning from a descendant variable.)
- If I **don't** know the patient's amount of *Oxidative stress and inflammation*, then learning the patient's degree of *Plaque progression* might well give me some extra information that helps me predict the patient's *Platelets*. (I'm not conditioning on the parents.)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful example.  The First three points are clear.  However, if I don't know _Oxidative stress and inflammation_, but I know about _Plaque progression_ but I am not conditioning on the parent _Atheroma_ do I learn about _Platelets_  form the common descendant _Myocardial ischemia and infarction _ ?  And if that is the case, would I also learn about  _Endothjelium_  ?

Comment: You're asking whether information can be transmitted between _Atheroma_ and _Platelets_ through the common child, _Myocardial ischemia and infarction_. But you're giving an example where information will be transmitted through the common parent, _Oxidative stress and inflammation_, because you aren't conditioning on it. Say we condition on _Oxidative stress and inflammation_ so we block that "back-door" flow of information. Then by the CMC, _Atheroma_ and _Platelets_ will be independent. So you see how the CMC rules out transmitting information through a common child.

Comment: Another even simpler example: say the graph is just $A \to C \leftarrow B$. Then the parent sets of $A$ and $B$ are the empty set, so you're always conditioning on their parents (trivially). Because neither $A$ nor $B$ is a descendant of the other, they are independent by the CMC, even though they have a common child $C$.

Comment: Now clear.  "Conditioning" blocks the flow of new information because you already know about it.  Thanks for your help.